# Putting new grips on handlebars

Tags: handlebars, grips

I have new flat bars and grips. What's the easiest way to slide the grips onto the bars?

Comment: Some modern grip styles use clamps with small 2 or 2.5mm hex bolts to clamp them down.  If yours are like this, then no lube should be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to a compressor, compressed air works well – use the hole in the end of the grip to blow in air while covering the other end of the bars with your hand (or something). The air escaping around the grip opens it up enough that it is easy to slide on.

Rubbing alcohol can be used as a lubricant. It will evaporate leaving the grips snug on the bars. Be wary of a lube that won't evaporate as the grips may tend to spin. Some people glue grips on, but that can make them pretty hard to get off without cutting.

Comment: You can also use a little bit of soapy water instead of rubbing alcohol as that will also disappear leaving nothing behind. This tends to work okay-ish. Depends on how strong you are.2

Comment: Glues are not as bad as you'd think - grips have a limited life and cutting them off for new ones is not the end of the world.  Having to cut them off to replace a shifter or brake lever, well that's annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Hair spray works best, lubricates when wet, sticks when it dries.

Comment: Technically true, but too short.  Answers that are this short are likely to be  deleted.  Try and include enough useful relevant info without going off topic.  Please use EDIT to expand your answer.